# django: Multiple objects are created from one form

Tags: python, django

I have a view, which takes a post request and creates an object if submitted form is valid. E.g.

```
def post(self, request):
    print "POST ARRIVED", request.POST
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ipset = form.save()
        print "Save called"
        redirect_url = u"%s?_q_=%s" % (
            reverse("mypage"), item.id)
```

Where form.save(), just calls Item.objects.create()

The thing is that as the result I have 3 items created from one request. (E.g. I see my prints are being called 3 times each, and I assume that Item.objects.create() is also called multiple times :()

Comment: Do you see "POST ARRIVED" 3 times as well?

Comment: So if that's happening then you're submitting the form 3 times or calling the POST function 3 times, if you fix that then you've fixed your issue

Comment: Yes, true. I am doing it with jquery. And it goes completely wrong on frontend

Comment: then add related javascript code please

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're submitting the POST request via ajax, you won't be able to do a server-side redirect. Instead, you would need to return the URL you want to redirect to, and do the redirection on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it already!

Comment: You should answer your own question to share the solution.